# 403 forbidden urlretrive Downloading archeive python 34

Tags: python, scrapy, urllib, permission-denied

I've a huge problem!! I need to download subtitles in archive, but all my efforts haven't brought me success!!
1. I've logged in using Scrapy

```
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'opensubtitles.org'
start_urls = ['http://www.opensubtitles.org/ru/login/redirect-%7Cru']

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'username': 'nothing_interesting_here', 'password': 'brute-force-me'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return
```

2. After I try to download the file and have the Error 403 Forbidden using
`urllib.request.urlretrieve` IF I DOWNLOAD MORE THAN 15 FILES, while python2's just `url.retrive` works!!

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/sub/vrf-108d030f/6633065', 'NAMEEEEEEEEEEEE.zip')
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'd change your personal information.

Comment: ...stealing your personal data from that website... _done_            ...changing your password... _done_                                        ...verdict: __don't share your passwords on StackOverflow!__                                                                       (this stuff about stealing ur data was a joke)

Comment: that doesn't matter, I'd like to solve the problem. I can make another account :D

Comment: Check out [their API page](https://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/ProgramsUsingAPI) for a bunch of sample ways to call into their service using their [official API](https://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC).  I strongly recommend using official APIs over scrapers.  There are over a dozen python programs on that page; I bet a few of them work well.  Also, you might be hitting download limits.  If so, they can be raised by paying [10EUR/year](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/support#vip)